# Angular UI-grid how to get file size using csv import feature?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using angular [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) to create a table. I have enabled the csv import feature, and this is working and is populating the table for me. Here is the issue I'm having:

Before I populate the table with the data, I want to verify that the csv file size being imported is less than a certain size (say 10MB). Is it possible to get this information from the api that ui-grid provides? I have searched the docs and can't find any reference to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According their APIs you cannot do this.But you can request this feature from them.

Here is the [**csv.js**](https://github.com/gkindel/CSV-JS) where you can request that feature.

This is the [**Ui Grid importer api GridOptions**](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.importer.api:GridOptions).But unfortunately there is no file size detection option there.